# How can I pass a callback to a generator that I pass to the "vo" library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, generator, nightmare

I am trying to understand how callbacks work so I created a function and passed a second argument named 'callback', which I call at the end of the function with 'callback(arr)' . However I am getting an error which says : "callback is not a function" ? Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

vo is a nodejs library that takes a generator function* () and runs all it's yields . It's basically a way to handle async code with less callbacks (yes I know I used a callback as well but that's pretty much a choice). A more popular library that does exactly the same thing is co. Link to vo: https://github.com/matthewmueller/vo

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');

function* MyFunction(query, callback) {
    arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        arr.push(yield Nightmare({
                show: true
            }).goto(`http://google.com`)
            .inject('js', 'jquery-3.1.0.js')
            .evaluate(() => {
                var title;
                title = 1
                extend = 2
                var img;
                img = 3
                var par;
                par = 4
                url = window.location.href;
                var par_arr = [5, 5, 5, 5];


                return {
                    title: title,
                    img: img,
                    par: par,
                    par_arr: par_arr,
                    url: url
                }

            }).end()
            .catch(function(error, nightmare) {

                console.error('Search failed:', error);
            }))
    }

    callback(arr);

    return arr;
}

vo(MyFunction)('query', (arr) => {
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: Why would you pass a callback to the generator rather than to .then on the returned promise?

Comment: `co` appears not only to be more popular but also better documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working in [my enviroment](https://ide.c9.io/jlvaquero/test);

```
var vo = require('vo');

function* idMaker(query, params){

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(query);
  }
 params.callback("callback value");
  return;
}

vo(idMaker)("param value",{callback: (value)=>console.log(value)}  );
```

Output:

```
param value
param value
param value
param value
param value
callback value
```

I have no time right now to read 'vo' docs to tell you why but I saw a exaplme [here](https://github.com/matthewmueller/vo/blob/master/examples/4-pipeline-multi-parallel.js).

Answer (score 0):

`vo` calls the function you give to it without arguments. That's why you get the error you are getting.

What you need to do is pass to `vo` a function that when called will call `MyFunction('query', (arr) => { console.log(arr); })`.

#### Anonymous generator

You could do it like this:

```
vo(function *() {
    return (yield* MyFunction('query', (arr) => {
        console.log("callback", arr);
    }));
}).then((arr) => {
    console.log("then", arr);
});
```

#### Using `co-bind`

Or as the [FAQ suggests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vo#faq), you can use `co-bind` Add the following `require`:

```
var cobind = require('co-bind');
```

And the the code above can become:

```
vo(cobind(MyFunction, undefined, 'query', (arr) => {
    console.log("callback", arr);
})).then((arr) => {
    console.log("then", arr);
});
```

Using `co-bind` rather than just doing `MyFunction.bind` is necessary because otherwise, `vo` won't treat the function as a generator.

Whether you use an anonymous generator or `co-bind`, the output I get is:

```
callback [ { img: 3,
    par: 4,
    par_arr: [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
    title: 1,
    url: 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' } ]
then [ { img: 3,
    par: 4,
    par_arr: [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
    title: 1,
    url: 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' } ]
```

**This being said, I don't see any benefit to using a callback. I would just use `.then()` after `vo` without passing a callback to `MyFunction`.** But even if you do not pass a callback, you still need to pass the `query` parameter to `MyFunction`, and can use one of the methods above.

Answer (score -2):

```
vo(MyFunction)('query', (arr) => {
    console.log(arr);
});
```

This looks wrong. You're feeding `vo` `MyFunction` and then presumably it returns a function you then fire with `'query'` and the fat arrow function as args. `MyFunction` would only work if vo returned `MyFunction` which would be kind of silly unless it were doing something to modify `MyFunction` in which case we really need to know what the heck `vo` is actually doing in order to answer this question.

Comment: vo is a function that takes a generator function* () and runs all it's yields . It's basically a way to handle async code without callbacks. A more popular library that does exactly the same thing is co. Link to vo: https://github.com/matthewmueller/vo

Comment: @RetroCode *"It's basically a way to handle async code without callbacks"* except it still uses callbacks..

Comment: @Erik Returning a closure from `vo` would be entirely sensible. There's nothing wrong with this call pattern.